# How to append content on body using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am trying to show popup on body not inside my-app.So how to show a popup on body using anular 2.I have tried but not working it is possible or not?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t4yerr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
name:string;
constructor(private domService: ModalService) {
this.name = `Angular!`;   
}

addToBody() {
this.domService.appendComponentToBody(DialogComponent);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want it to be outside your app?

Comment: I want to show vertical scroll bar also..this is better to avoid css tweaks

Comment: I think mostly done but not working..I have edited my code..check and give me solution

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is wrong. What you do is simply copying HTML entry, but this won't be enough because you lose the connection from Angular to this HTML element.

There are various solutions to that problem, however you can look at e.g. [at this article](https://medium.com/@caroso1222/angular-pro-tip-how-to-dynamically-create-components-in-body-ba200cc289e6) (the code below **is copied from the article**)

```
import {
    Injectable,
    Injector,
    ComponentFactoryResolver,
    EmbeddedViewRef,
    ApplicationRef
} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DomService {

  constructor(
      private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
      private appRef: ApplicationRef,
      private injector: Injector
  ) { }

  appendComponentToBody(component: any) {
    // 1. Create a component reference from the component 
    const componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
      .resolveComponentFactory(component)
      .create(this.injector);

    // 2. Attach component to the appRef so that it's inside the ng component tree
    this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

    // 3. Get DOM element from component
    const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
      .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

    // 4. Append DOM element to the body
    document.body.appendChild(domElem);

    // 5. Wait some time and remove it from the component tree and from the DOM
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.appRef.detachView(componentRef.hostView);
        componentRef.destroy();
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

This way, you not only relocate your HTML object. You keep the binding from Angular to this HTML element.

Another way is looking at a [ready modal library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-simple-modal) that does everything for you (including hosting your component in body). Additionally, you can check [their implementation](https://github.com/KevCJones/ngx-simple-modal/blob/c6640f5d002215820ed01d16dd66e26b839afc72/src/simple-modal/simple-modal.service.ts#L121) of the component-to-body relocation

Comment: I have edited my code by(at this article) :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t4yerr?file=src/app/app.component.ts   but not working?

Comment: I think mostly done but not working..I have edited my code..check and give me solution